# Cassandra Astyanax documentation

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I am trying to use Astyanax for Cassandra with Java. I tried the example at https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started. I have the code which I have just copied from this link:

```
package def;

import com.netflix.astyanax.AstyanaxContext;
import com.netflix.astyanax.Keyspace;
import com.netflix.astyanax.MutationBatch;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.NodeDiscoveryType;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.OperationResult;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.ConnectionException;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor;
import com.netflix.astyanax.impl.AstyanaxConfigurationImpl;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.Column;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.ColumnFamily;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.ColumnList;
import com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.StringSerializer;
import com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftFamilyFactory;

public class sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster("Test Cluster")
    .forKeyspace("KeyspaceName")
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(10)
        .setSeeds("127.0.0.1:9160")
    )
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    Keyspace keyspace = context.getEntity();

    ColumnFamily<String, String> CF_USER_INFO =
              new ColumnFamily<String, String>(
                "Standard1",              // Column Family Name
                StringSerializer.get(),   // Key Serializer
                StringSerializer.get());  // Column Serializer

    // Inserting data
    MutationBatch m = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch();

    m.withRow(CF_USER_INFO, "acct1234")
      .putColumn("firstname", "john", null)
      .putColumn("lastname", "smith", null)
      .putColumn("address", "555 Elm St", null)
      .putColumn("age", 30, null);

    m.withRow(CF_USER_INFO, "acct1234")
      .incrementCounterColumn("loginCount", 1);

    try {
      OperationResult<Void> result = m.execute();
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
    }

    System.out.println("completed the task!!!");

    OperationResult<ColumnList<String>> result =
              keyspace.prepareQuery(CF_USER_INFO)
                .getKey("Key1")
                .execute();
            ColumnList<String> columns = result.getResult();

            // Lookup columns in response by name 
            int age        = columns.getColumnByName("age").getIntegerValue();
            long counter   = columns.getColumnByName("loginCount").getLongValue();
            String address = columns.getColumnByName("address").getStringValue();

            // Or, iterate through the columns
            for (Column<String> c : result.getResult()) {
              System.out.println(c.getName());
            }
    }

}
```

But when I run this I am getting an exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
completed the task!!!
Exception in thread "main" com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=0(0), attempts=1] InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace KeyspaceName does not exist)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:52)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:229)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:180)
    at def.sample.main(sample.java:68)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace KeyspaceName does not exist)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$set_keyspace_result.read(Cassandra.java:4874)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:489)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:476)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    ... 4 more
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? There is no proper documentation also available for this. So, can you just help me out. And even give me some links where I can get more examples on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
why:Keyspace KeyspaceName does not exist
```

The error above is pretty self explanatory. The keyspace does not exists when the application connect to the localhost. So ensure that you create the keyspace and then re-run your application.

---

From the comment, I think you want to look into [this](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/issues/9) . Excerpt from the thread,

> The Keyspace serves as a client only and does not create the keyspace
>   or column family on cassandra. You can use the AsytanaxContext.Builder
>   to construct a Cluster interface through which you can actually create
>   the keyspace and column families.

This unit test in this [link](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/src/test/java/com/netflix/astyanax/thrift/ThrifeKeyspaceImplTest.java) should provide you sufficient information on how to create keyspace in your cluster.

Comment: ok.. Is there any way to create the keyspace in the code itself? I am not getting any way to do this. This will work when I have keyspace and column family created already. But I don't want to crete it before. How can I do this through the code?

Comment: @shalki i'm not that familiar into astyanax but I think you can create the keyspace. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is written to talk to a running instance of a Cassandra server on your localhost at 127.0.0.1.  If you have Cassandra running elsewhere, or not at all, then you'll need to install and set up that server environment prior to executing your code.